# Custom Adapter - Android Studio

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, arraylist, custom-adapter

So i tried to do a custom adapter, but even tho there are no errors and even tho arrayList is not empty -i am sure about that i can print something from it- , it's not working, so here is my customAdapter class:

```
public class CurrentListingsCustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<CurrentListingsClass> {

    public ArrayList<CurrentListingsClass> currentListingsClassArrayList;
    public Activity context;

    public CurrentListingsCustomAdapter(ArrayList<CurrentListingsClass> currentListingsClassArrayList, Activity context) {
        super(context, R.layout.custom_view, currentListingsClassArrayList);
        this.currentListingsClassArrayList = currentListingsClassArrayList;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        View customView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_view, null, true);

        TextView nameView = customView.findViewById(R.id.customTextView);
        nameView.setText(currentListingsClassArrayList.get(position).getDetails());

        return customView;
    }
}
```

here is my custom_view.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/customTextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="53dp"
        android:gravity="center|center_horizontal"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textSize="24sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by "it isn't working". Can you explain what isn't working? Have you set breakpoints or added logging to see if your adapter is being instantiated? Is `getView()` getting called? You need to give us a bit more information.

Comment: In any case, when you call `LayoutInflator.inflate()` the third parameter should be `false` since you are passing `null` as the parent `View`.

Comment: Change `layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_view, null, true);` to `layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_view, parent, false);` There may be other issues, but this is a necessary first step.

Comment: @DavidWasser by 'isnt working' i mean even tho arrayList isn't empty, what i want to display isn't being displayed, and i am sorry but i don't know what a breakpoint is i am just a beginner but i'll try to learn and try it.

Comment: @BenP. i tried that but it didn't work

Comment: You can also just add debug logging to your code. Use `Log.d("MyApp", "message you want to see ...")`, then check Logcat for your messages. You can use this to determine if the code is actually being executed, and also you can log the values of any variables, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Override this method in your class like this.

```
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return currentListingsClassArrayList.size();
    }
```

Comment: Set breakpint at this line and make sure your list has size.

`return currentListingsClassArrayList.size();`

Comment: i don't  really know what that is, i am a beginner

Comment: In android studio click next to the line number and a red circle like the image should appear. The name of this red circle is ```breakpoint```. After that run program as debug mode (Shift + F9), then the program stoped in which line you make ```breakpoint``` and a window opens like an image that tells you the program info from start to your ```breakpoint```. So you can easily show your ```currentListingsClassArrayList``` info. Make sure it has a size, for example in the image as you can see my ```currentListingsClassArrayList``` has 3 objects.

Image link
[https://pasteboard.co/JDmaqG2.png]

Comment: i tried that breakpoints but i cannot see your image, and that debug log was so long where should i look at?

Comment: [https://pasteboard.co/JDmAzxF.png] Image link. Debug tab -> variable. you can see your `currentListingsClassArrayList` object